# Regex Basics: grab text between two constants

Tags: php, regex

Stuck on a (rather simple) regex problem in PHP.

Buried in a mess of text is this section:

```
  &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td id=&quot;descriptionArea&quot;&gt;
            Customer request to remove &quot;Intro - 01/13/09&quot; video clip.
            &lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
```

I want whatever is between:

```
descriptionArea&quot;&gt;
```

...and...

```
&lt;/td&gt;
```

A friend suggested:

```
$pattern = '&lt;td=&quot;descriptionArea&quot;&gt;\s*(.*?)\s*&lt;';
$clean = preg_replace("'[\n\r\s\t]'","",$text); // to rid of line breaks
preg_match($pattern, $clean, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'q'
```

I suppose the second question is whether preg_match is the correct PHP function for this, also.  Should I be using ereg instead?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `preg_*` functions, the first character or the pattern is treated as delimiter:

> The expression must be enclosed in the delimiters, a forward slash (`/`), for example. Any character can be used for delimiter as long as it's not alphanumeric or backslash (`\`). If the delimiter character has to be used in the expression itself, it needs to be escaped by backslash. Since PHP 4.0.4, you can also use Perl-style `()`, `{}`, `[]`, and `<>` matching delimiters.
>   — [Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible) – Introduction](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php)

So you don’t need to escape or replace the `&` characters as others said. Instead use proper delimiters and escape those characters inside the expression:

```
'/&lt;td id=&quot;descriptionArea&quot;&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/td&gt;/'
```

Comment: Note also that the OP's regex was incomplete: it started "<td=&quot;" instead of "<td id=&quot;". But the main problem was the delimiters, and this is the first answer to correctly address that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to escape out the "&", like wombleton says, and also enclose your pattern with forward slashes, like $pattern = "/pattern/";

The below code returns an array with some ugly stuff in it but at least it returns a match.. :)

```
$description = " &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td id=&quot;descriptionArea&quot;&gt;
            Customer request to remove &quot;Intro - 01/13/09&quot; video clip.
            &lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;";

$pattern = "/&lt;td.*[&]quot;descriptionArea[&]quot;[&]gt;\s*(.*?)\s*.*?lt/";
$clean = preg_replace("'[\n\r\s\t]'","",$description); // to rid of line breaks

preg_match($pattern, $clean, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a nicer version.  Get rid of all the HTML encoding so you can use a standard HTML-parsing regex:

```
$pattern = '/<.*?id="descriptionArea">(.*?)<\/td>/';
$clean = preg_replace("'[\n\r\t]'","",htmlspecialchars_decode($description)); 
preg_match($pattern, $clean, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's interpreting the ampersands as control characters of some kind. I can't find a reference to support this however.

Try replacing all of the instances of `&` with `[&]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the text between two *constants*, wouldn't it be easier to use good ol'  strpos?

**EDIT**

e.g.

```
$string = 'text to be >searched< within';
$const1 = '>';
$const2 = '<';
$start = strpos($string, $const1);
$end = strpos($string, $const2, $start + strlen($const1));
$result = substr($string, $start, $end - $start);
```

I haven't run it, so it might be buggy, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

What is you used the following for $pattern?

```
$pattern = '(?s:descriptionArea&quot;&gt;(.*)&lt;/td&gt;)';
```

I don't know PHP, but the RegEx appears to work within Regular Expression Designer when I tested it. The option of (?s:) is 'Singleline On'.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are getting comes from preg_* functions using the first character of the pattern as a delimiter (in this case "&"), and everything after the second occurrence of the delimiter as modifiers (such as "i" for case-insensitivity.)

In this case, it thinks you are looking for `lt;td=` and you want modifiers `quot;descriptionArea&quot;&gt;\s*(.*?)\s*&lt;`. The first modifier "q" does not make sense, and it bails.